# Google Big Query and Google Analytics - convert INTEGER to TIME

Tags: google-bigquery, data-conversion, google-analytics-4

I have a problem with data from Google Analytics 4.
I have a total time duration metric and its in BQ but as integer.
I need to change it TIME since im using the data in PowerBi.
Any ideas?

I tried all the solutions in the internet - none of them is working.
I tried to transform the data in PowerBi - but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as to what the value of integer is.
It could be

1. integer representation of date as 20240117 -(2024 year 01 month 17 date)
2. integer representation of time as 113000 -( 11 PM 30 min 00 sec)
3. integer representation of timestamp as 20240117010110 (Y,M,D,H,M,S)
4. It could be the number of minutes/seconds as a quantity.

Assuming case 1: Use PARSE_DATE with following parse string indicating %Y year, %m month, %d date

```
select PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', cast(20240117 as string))
```

Result: 2024-01-17

Assuming case 2: Use PARSE_TIME with following parse string indicating %I Hours %M Minutes, %S seconds

```
select PARSE_TIME('%I%M%S', cast(113000 as string))
```

Result: 11:30:00

Case 3: Use

```
select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d%I%M%S', cast(20240117010110 as string))
```

Result: 2024-01-17 01:01:10 UTC

Case 4: You need to know from when the time is being counted. and convert that seconds/minutes into days and add to that base date.

Find Documentation here [PARSE_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) , [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date), [PARSE_TIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#parse_time)

Comment: I have a time duration from GA4 represented as hh:mm:ss - and in BQ its qualified as integer and its represented by for example 2967 for duration 00:00:007 so that's incorrect.
How i can cgange it to time/timestamp?

Comment: How does 2967 represents 00:00:007? You should give the exact values that you have for that time duration. Above example is confusing. After you provide the exact values you have I can suggest a parsing method for that.

Comment: Okay,let me explain this:
In Funnel I see landing page for example rezepte/bramble - and total session duration 00:00:07
In BQ I see the same landing page and the total session duration is represented by number 6. Thats all. Thats all I have.

Comment: Still not able to understand your data. Please add a detailed sample data in question.

Comment: Refrain from jumping into an answer immediately if the question is unclear. Help Ola to further clarify and then answer the question.

Comment: I would love to clarify it more.
I have ETL called funnel when I can import the metrics from Google Analytics 4. 
And in that tool i see Total duration session represented in format hh:mm:ss
Then I export the fields to Google Big Query, and I see that this field is defined as INTEGER the data is in format integer not hh:mm:ss and I need to see this as hh:mm:ss
Is there any way to transform this in correct format?
For example in ETL tool I see duration 00:00:13 but in BTQ its 297